# Pack 4 byte integers into bytearray or array

Tags: python, python-3.x, integer, arrays, padding

I can't seem to find out how to do this, so it may not be that simple after all. I looked [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6076300/python-pack-4-byte-integer-with-bytes-in-bytearray-struct-pack), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5302374/packing-4-integers-as-one-byte), and many others, but I can't get the type of answer I'm looking for. Most of the posts I read use the `struct.pack` or `struct.pack_into`, but the problem is that I don't really know a priory the size of the array I need, and I wouldn't like to create one to store temporarily the integer values. So I thought that I could use the `bytearray` instead, but I don't know how to add 4-byte integers to it.

```
>>> b = bytearray()
>>> for i in range(100):
...   b.append(i)
... 
>>> print(b)
bytearray(b'\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\t\n\x0b\x0c\r\x0e\x0f\x10\x11\x12\x13\x14\x15\x16\x17\x18\x19\x1a\x1b\x1c\x1d\x1e\x1f !"#$%&\'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`abc')
>>> print(list(b))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99]
>>> import sys
>>> sys.getsizeof(b)
161
```

So the byte array doesn't contain 4-byte integers (which is what I need). So then I would have to use some sort of padding with zeros in order to get 4-byte integers? Is there a function that I can use to convert the integer passed to append to the type of integer I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`array` type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html) to store fixed-sized binary data, where the number of values is variable:

```
import array

values = array.array('I')
values.fromlist([i for i in range(100)])
bytes = values.tobytes()
```

What C type you pick depends on your system architecture; you may have to pick one based on the `array.itemsize` attribute; on my 64-bit Mac `I` uses 4 bytes to store an unsigned integer:

```
>>> import array
>>> values = array.array('I')
>>> values.itemsize
4
>>> values.fromlist([i for i in range(100)])
>>> len(values.tobytes())
400
```

The byte order is also machine dependent; if you need to have big-endian bytes, but your machine uses a little-endian architecture, use [`array.byteswap()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html#array.array.byteswap) to swap the order before converting to bytes:

```
import sys

if sys.byteorder == 'little':
    values.byteswap()  # convert to big-endian before writing to a file
values.tofile(fileobj)
```

Comment: It seems though that you need to know _a priori_ the size of the array for its construction, don't you?

Comment: @aaragon: no, you don't. Arrays contain an arbitrary number of elements. You only need to know the target byte size.

Comment: Great, I just saw the `append` method for the array class. Should I use `len(values) * values.itemsize` to get the total size stored, or is there a shortcut?

Comment: There is no shortcut; multiplying the length by itemsize is how I'd do it.

Comment: Just a quick question about the internals of the array. I don't know how it's implemented internally, but I guess that if it has an `append` method it is like a double liked list, is it? This means that inserting an item at position 0 after the array is formed can be done without manipulating the rest of the array, correct?

Comment: @aaragon: it is not a doubly-linked list; it is a dynamically grown array.

Comment: So then inserting items one by one is extremely expensive :/

Comment: See the [`array` source](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/241f9aa9fb89/Modules/arraymodule.c#l44); like Python `list` objects arrays are overallocated and resized as needed. Inserting values at the start will indeed require a `memmove` call to move everything after the insert up a spot.

Comment: @aaragon: consider reversing, appending, the reversing again as an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
>>> import struct
>>> b = bytearray()
>>> b = b""
>>> for i in range(100):
...     b += struct.pack("<i", i)
... 
>>> len(b)
400
>>> b
b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00\x06\x00\x00\x00\x07\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00\t\x00\x00\x00\n\x00\x00\x00\x0b\x00\x00\x00\x0c\x00\x00\x00\r\x00\x00\x00\x0e\x00\x00\x00\x0f\x00\x00\x00\x10\x00\x00\x00\x11\x00\x00\x00\x12\x00\x00\x00\x13\x00\x00\x00\x14\x00\x00\x00\x15\x00\x00\x00\x16\x00\x00\x00\x17\x00\x00\x00\x18\x00\x00\x00\x19\x00\x00\x00\x1a\x00\x00\x00\x1b\x00\x00\x00\x1c\x00\x00\x00\x1d\x00\x00\x00\x1e\x00\x00\x00\x1f\x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00!\x00\x00\x00"\x00\x00\x00#\x00\x00\x00$\x00\x00\x00%\x00\x00\x00&\x00\x00\x00\'\x00\x00\x00(\x00\x00\x00)\x00\x00\x00*\x00\x00\x00+\x00\x00\x00,\x00\x00\x00-\x00\x00\x00.\x00\x00\x00/\x00\x00\x000\x00\x00\x001\x00\x00\x002\x00\x00\x003\x00\x00\x004\x00\x00\x005\x00\x00\x006\x00\x00\x007\x00\x00\x008\x00\x00\x009\x00\x00\x00:\x00\x00\x00;\x00\x00\x00<\x00\x00\x00=\x00\x00\x00>\x00\x00\x00?\x00\x00\x00@\x00\x00\x00A\x00\x00\x00B\x00\x00\x00C\x00\x00\x00D\x00\x00\x00E\x00\x00\x00F\x00\x00\x00G\x00\x00\x00H\x00\x00\x00I\x00\x00\x00J\x00\x00\x00K\x00\x00\x00L\x00\x00\x00M\x00\x00\x00N\x00\x00\x00O\x00\x00\x00P\x00\x00\x00Q\x00\x00\x00R\x00\x00\x00S\x00\x00\x00T\x00\x00\x00U\x00\x00\x00V\x00\x00\x00W\x00\x00\x00X\x00\x00\x00Y\x00\x00\x00Z\x00\x00\x00[\x00\x00\x00\\\x00\x00\x00]\x00\x00\x00^\x00\x00\x00_\x00\x00\x00`\x00\x00\x00a\x00\x00\x00b\x00\x00\x00c\x00\x00\x00'
```

For more info on the struct packing codes, see https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/struct.html. My code uses `i` for int, and `<` for little-endian.