# Is there a better way to convert string data to 32 bit hex

Tags: python

I'm using following code to print string data in the form of 32 bit hex

```
hdata = binascii.hexlify(bytearray(data))
n = 8
split_str = [hdata[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(hdata), n)]
for st in split_str:
    print st[6:8]+st[4:6]+st[2:4]+st[0:2]
```

I feel this is not very efficient, please suggest better way to do this.

If `n` is constant like `8` I can write in the following way,

```
split_str = [a[i+6:i+8]+a[i+4:i+6]+a[i+2:i+4]+a[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(a), 8)]
```

Comment: `hexlify` (and a slice as appropriate) is sufficient to answer the question in the title. Be more precise.

Comment: You mean you want little-endian representations per 4 bytes of data?

Comment: Looks to me like this might be a dupe of [Pack 4 byte integers into bytearray or array](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25643201); you can then hexlify the `.tobytes()` result.